# html replace px with nothing

Tags: html

I have a table column.
I have always use px for the width.

```
<td width="100px"></td>
```

but suddenly today my superior told me not to use px since without it also will be the same.

```
<td width="100"></td>
```

this one means that it is also 100px? I have never learn it like this. I only know that i can use px, em or % but not without it. is it the right way? will different browser have different result? is it true that 100 = 100px?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: That's a difference between html attributes and actual styling. Same as for images, the width and height attribute are used without px.

Comment: Roberto Wilko: What do you mean by loosing clarity? Its just wrong to put 'px' into html atributes and everyone who knows basics of html will know that dimensions are in px...

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake. because i am not to familiar with the different between css style and html attributes. @Gatekeeper i am confuse. thats why i am asking about this.

Comment: @Nur Aini: See My answer given below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `width` attribute is not css, it's old-school HTML.

If you want to change the style of the cell you use the style attribute:

```
<td style="width:100px"></td>
```

I would recommend using an external stylesheet instead of adding the styles inline. You can probably save a lot of bandwidth from not repeating the inline styles over and over, even if they are machine generated.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I am a new staff in my company. For now i have to follow their way of styling and everything. Thats why i had this question..

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: True, but the question was kind of flawed so I answered what was meant :)

Answer (score 2):

In HTML 4.01 the attribute [**width**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh773371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be defined as given below:

```
 <element width="pixels | percentage% | relative*" ... >
```

So there is no need to add `px` after `width` or `height` according to HTML 4.01

While In CSS you need to add `px` while styling an element's [**width**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like given below:

```
<td style="width:100px"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `width` attribute accepts numbers (interpreted as pixels) or a number+% sign (interpreted as percent). Browsers may accept the 'px' suffix, but that is not per the spec.

So, your superior is correct.

However, if you prefer to use CSS for this, then px is an appropriate and required suffix:

```
<td style="width: 100px"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The width attribute of `<td>` is deprecated in [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6). It used to accept a [length](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#Length), which is a number in pixels or a certain percentage.

The currently preferred way is to specify the width using CSS. In CSS, you always have to [specify a unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-length) (e.g. "px"), except when the value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I will better suggest not to use the width property of the **td** tag, since it has been deprecated from the HTML 4.01 and may not be supported in future browsers. Use CSS instead. And for this particular question you can use any of the two notations you have mentioned.

Comment: There are several tags, including new ones, that should get width and height attributes. img, video, input[type=image]

Comment: Ya I found my mistake and made the change in the response. Thank you for pointing out the mistake.